# Bind independent events to the dynamic added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this Button click code that is responsible to add Dynamic data

```
$("#AddSec").click(function() {

    $("<div />", {
            "class": "wrapper"
        })
        .append($('<span />', {
            "class": "AddCol",
            id: "AddCol" + i
        }).html('(+)col'))
        .append($('<span />', {
            "class": "RemCol",
            id: "RemCol" + i
        }).html('(-)col'))
        .appendTo("#data");
    $("<div />", {
            "class": "SecStyle",
            id: "Section" + i
        })
        .append($("<div/>").attr('class', 'well droppedFields ui-sortable Resizable'))
        .appendTo("#data");
    i++;
});
```

Following is the Output for this code

```
<div id="data" style="height: 100px; line-height: 20px; width: 100%; display: table;">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <span class="AddCol" id="AddCol1">(+)col</span>
        <span class="RemCol" id="RemCol1">(-)col</span>
    </div>
    <div class="SecStyle" id="Section1">
        <div class="well droppedFields ui-sortable Resizable ui-resizable ui-droppable">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper"><span class="AddCol" id="AddCol2">(+)col</span>
        <span class="RemCol" id="RemCol2">(-)col</span>
    </div>
    <div class="SecStyle" id="Section2">
        <div class="well droppedFields ui-sortable Resizable ui-resizable ui-droppable">
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90; display: block;">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is the html layout for above output
[image]

(+)col (-)col
are

```
<span class="AddCol" id="AddCol1">(+)col</span>
<span class="RemCol" id="RemCol1">(-)col</span>
```

respectively
with different ids everytime

Now i have to handle the click event for every (+)col , independently for each time the dynamic section added

can any one help to keep me close to this

Comment: Learn event delegation for elements created dynamically and usage of class selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dynamically created buttons you would use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.AddCol', function() {
    //your code here
    // this.id gives you the id of the button clicked
});

 $(document).on('click', '.RemCol', function() {
    //your code here
    // this.id gives you the id of the button clicked
});
```

To improve performance, if `#data` is not dynamically created, use:

```
$('#data').on('click', '.AddCol', .....); //and
$('#data').on('click', '.RemCol', .....);
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.AddCol,.RemCol', function() {
     //your code here
     alert( this.id ); // gives you the id of the button clicked
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="AddCol" id="AddCol1">(+)col</span>
<span class="RemCol" id="RemCol1">(-)col</span>
<span class="AddCol" id="AddCol2">(+)col</span> 
<span class="RemCol" id="RemCol2">(-)col</span>
```

Reference:

-- [**jQuery.live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

```
$( document ).delegate( selector, events, data, handler );  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$( document ).on( events, selector, data, handler );        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: `this` will be the document, not the element clicked. You need `event.currentTarget`

Comment: Sorry, I believe you're mistaken.

Comment: Hrmmm, a quick JSfiddle shows you're correct! Do you know by chance if that's a more recent change? I've been using `event.currentTarget` for a long time now because it used to return document! http://jsfiddle.net/wnLxghyw/

Comment: I also added a code snippet to the question. To my knowledge, this has always been the behavior .... please take a look at: [**jQuery.live()**](http://api.jquery.com/live/) for detailed documentation about event delegation.

Comment: suppose we have another snippet

<span class="AddCol" id="AddCol2">(+)col</span>
<span class="RemCol" id="RemCol2">(-)col</span>

Comment: @ColdCoffee Don't use IDs. You don't need them. Just use classes to identify things. See my answer below as a way to look up the closest `.wrapper` which gives you the current row's scope. From there you can use `$wrapper.find(...)` to look up elements in the context of that row.

Comment: Use this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63517/bind-independent-events-to-the-dynamic-added-elements

Comment: How can I be of help?

Comment: can you talk litle in our chatroom

Answer (score 0):

You will use event bubbling and event delegation in jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Something like this:

```
$('#data').on('click', '.AddCol', function(event) {
  var $addCol = $(event.currentTarget);
  var $wrapper = $addCol.closest('.wrapper');
});
```

The reason you can't use `$(this)` is because you're actually **binding** on the static/pre-defined `#data` element. But it will capture bubbled events and trigger from anything matching the `.AddCol` selector. The element that triggered the event is in `event.currentTarget`

Answer (score 0):

You could add dinamically click listener to each added element as follows:

```
var $wrapper = $("<div />", { "class": "wrapper" });
var $spanplus = $('<span />', { "class": "AddCol", id: "AddCol" + i}).html('(+)col');
//Binds click event
$spanplus.on('click',function(){ //Your onclick code});

//Append the span to the wrapper
$wrapper.append($spanplus);
```